Remove help text from lightning-input type date
Woke up today and all of my lightning-input type date components now suddenly show the date format under the input field. The picture below illustrates this. Any suggestions for a fix?


Check this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/425617/how-to-remove-expected-date-format-in-lightning-input-element
