How to remove date format stamp at field level in salesforce date field
Good Morning! Hope all are doing great!
There is a date field in our salesforce org we used and due to recent salesforce update date format stamp is displaying at every date field level. Can anyone sugegst how to remove that date stamp from field level .
please check attachment for reference.

Regards,
Basha

Refer to this: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007ifkQdSAI

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/425598/lightning-input-type-date-hide-date-format-below-the-field
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/425617/how-to-remove-expected-date-format-in-lightning-input-element

